# Can I apply for a Schengen visa from a country in which I'm a student but not a resident?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am an international student studying in Singapore and need to apply for a Schengen visa. Can I do it in Singapore, or do I have to do it from within my home country?

Comment: Mostly, it's possible, if you're a resident in a 3rd country (studying actually means being a resident, you're not a tourist). There are bunch of similar questions on this site: like [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60474/apply-for-schengen-visa-in-a-third-country) or [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94859/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-from-a-country-other-than-my-country-of-residence). But we need to know your nationality.

Comment: In addition we need to know how long your visa was originally issue for and the amount of unspent leave currently.